# Excel VBA - Workbook Level Variable Declaration

Tags: vba, excel

Say, I want to declare a workbook level (global scope) variable which other procedures can review to execute code. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Public Scope**

Public variables have the broadest scope of all variables. A public variable is recognized by every module in the active workbook. To make a public variable available to other workbooks, from a new workbook select the workbook containing the public variable in the Available References box of the References dialog box (from a module sheet, click References on the Tools menu).

**Things to remember:**

- A public variable, like a module-level variable, is declared at the top of the module, above the first procedure definition.
- A public variable cannot be declared within a procedure.
- A public variable is always declared with a "Public" statement.
- A public variable may be declared in any module sheet.

Example:

```
Public SalesPrice As Integer
Public UnitsSold As Integer
Public CostPerUnit As Integer
Private Markup As Long

Sub CDSales()
    ...    
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks, I should have known that. Thats a very well put answer.