# public variable not being recognized in separate workbook module?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to declare a public variable `strFileDate` that I would like to store an input box value to be later referenced when another workbook (separate wb) is opened and a macro is run within that new wb. I declare a public variable as so:

```
Public strFileDate as string 
Option Explicit
Sub Update_Data()
  Dim strFileDate As String: strFileDate = InputBox("Enter Folder Date (mm.dd.yy)", Default:=Format("mm.dd.yy"))
  ...
end sub
```

```
Option Explicit
Sub Open_Separate_File    
  Dim basepath as string: basepath = "C:\...."
  Dim strFileName as string: strFileName = "test_file_"
  Thisworkbook.SaveCopyAs basepath & strFileName & strFileDate & ".xlsx" 
End Sub
```

whenever I open up the workbook containing `Open_Separate_File`, it says that `strFileDate` is not defined, and I assume it's due to the `Option Explicit` label at the top of both modules. Is there a way around this without omitting `Option Explicit`?

Comment: I would give this a read; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-scope-and-visibility

Comment: @BigBen it's saying that non-private variable declaration is automatically in the public scope, so is it `option explicit` causing this error? In that article, I don't see that declaration

Comment: "If you declare a module-level variable as public, it's available to all procedures in the project." Emphasis on "*in the project*."

Comment: @BigBen ah, gotcha, missed that part. So since this variable is trying to be declared in a separate workbook module, I need to declare it, again? Only reason why I am trying to avoid this, is that I don't want the user to have to type in a date in an input box, twice

Comment: @bigben would I just declare it like `Global strFileDate as string`?

Comment: No, https://stackoverflow.com/a/3815797/9245853.

Comment: @BigBen So is this not doable?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32046869/excel-vba-workbook-level-variable-declaration) may be helpful, but I would not go this route myself.

Comment: @BigBen I went this route, but its still not functioning. I may just be SOL and have the user input the date, twice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you can't rely on variables retaining their value longer than a macro's run-time. All sorts of Excel actions can clear saved variables, such as saving a workbook, and you'll never be able to access them across workbooks without explicitly using get/set macros (which might not work anyway, due to the variable values possibly getting cleared).

The best way to retain this sort of data is with the `SaveSetting` and `GetSetting` functions.

In your first workbook, you could save the user-entered value saved, with something like this:

```
Dim strFileDate As String
strFileDate = InputBox("Enter Folder Date (mm.dd.yy)", Default:=Format("mm.dd.yy"))
SaveSetting "ExampleAppName", "ExampleSectionName", "FileDate", strFileDate
```

In your second workbook, you would access that value, with something like this:

```
Dim strFileDate As String
strFileDate = GetSetting("ExampleAppName", "ExampleSectionName", "FileDate")
```

If you want to clean it up after you're finished running whatever's in the second workbook, you would delete it with:

```
DeleteSetting "ExampleAppName", "ExampleSectionName", "FileDate"
```

Comment: when you say `ExampleAppName`, `ExampleSectionName`, and `FileDate`, do you mean `workbook_name`, `module name`, and I'm still confused about `FileDate`?

Comment: Good approach but, a) what if the user doesn't have access to write to the registry and b) two people try to access and save at the same time?

Comment: @NidenK Those are just examples, you can use whatever strings you'd like (generally, it would be something descriptive of what your app is called). It just has to be the exact same set of strings for both setting/getting the data. `FileDate` can also be any string you want, it's just a description of what data you're storing.

Comment: @KostasK. If you're running this on Windows, you just need permissions to read/write `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`. I've never seen a group permissions so restrictive to disallow that, seeing as many Windows applications rely on it. In terms of two people doing it at the same time, it's specific to the current user on a given machine; as far as I know, Windows doesn't ever let you have a user logged onto the same machine twice.

Comment: @JoshEller  I added in that stuff, and I'm still getting a `variable not defined` error when the other workbook opens and the module is about to run; this brings me back to my original problem

Comment: @NidenK Well, what variable isn't defined?

Comment: @JoshEller `strFileDate` in the workbook module that I'm calling upon (the second workbook)

Comment: @NidenK Add `Dim strFileDate as String` then, as shown in the answer. If you're using that variable in only one sub, put it at the top of that sub. If you're using it across multiple subs, put it at the top of the module (below `Option Explicit`).

Comment: that did it, I just needed to place `strFileDate` in between `Option Explicit` and the `Sub`

Thanks a bunch!